# Create Proc fs dir and entry under a already existing subdir kernel 3.11 or higher?

Tags: linux, proc, createfile

I know this question has been asked more the once. But really nowhere a good answer. In despit the fact that I'm already using since very long time the answers here , it is the very first time that I could not find a solution.
Here My code which works perfect to:

First create a dir under /proc then a second dir then a entry.
The entry is empty but writable. Works perfect.

Some extra info ubuntu 14.04 kernel update 3.13.0-49-generic. x86_64

Here the code.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

static int len,temp;

static char *msg;
static char *dirname="mydriver";
static char *dirname2="settings";
struct proc_dir_entry *parent;
struct proc_dir_entry *parent2;
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp )
{
    if(count>temp){count=temp;}
    temp=temp-count;
    copy_to_user(buf,msg, count);
    if(count==0){temp=len;}

    return count;
}

static ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp,const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp)
{
    copy_from_user(msg,buf,count);
    len=count;
    temp=len;

    return count;
}

struct file_operations proc_fops = {
    read: read_proc,
    write: write_proc
};

static void create_new_proc_entry(void)
{
    parent = proc_mkdir(dirname, NULL);
    parent2 = proc_mkdir(dirname2,parent);
    proc_create("private_setting",0644,parent2,&proc_fops);
    msg=kmalloc(GFP_KERNEL,10*sizeof(char));
}


static int proc_init (void)
{
 create_new_proc_entry();
 return 0;
}

static void proc_cleanup(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry("private_setting",parent2);
    proc_remove(parent2);
    proc_remove(parent);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

The question is how to create the dir's and entry's under an already existing subdir. like for example /proc/driver.

I know the first parent is created with NULL which means /proc.

But what to set in place off NULL to have /proc/driver. I tried so what all. Nothing works.

I found the solution to create the dir and entry under /proc/driver.

Just replace in the code above:

```
static char *dirname="mydriver";
```

with line below:

```
static char *dirname="driver/mydriver";
```

Comment: I found the solution, I mention it here since a lot off persons where looking for it. Just to create my /proc dir's and file under subdir /proc/driver.

Comment: Many persons where looking for this answer. This works perfect by me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out to compile this code on kernel 3.2. Unfortunately it did not compile. I well found the small change so that it works on kernel 3.2.
The nice thing off it is that with that small change It also works on 3.13.
With other words the code compiles and works perfect from kernel 3.2 up to 3.13 (tested) Gues it also will be ok for last linux kernel versions.

Here the full code revised.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

static int len,temp;

static char *msg;
static char *dirname="driver/mydriver";
static char *dirname2="settings";
struct proc_dir_entry *subdirparent;
struct proc_dir_entry *parent;
struct proc_dir_entry *parent2;
static ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp,char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp )
{
    if(count>temp){count=temp;}
    temp=temp-count;
    copy_to_user(buf,msg, count);
    if(count==0){temp=len;}

    return count;
}

static ssize_t write_proc(struct file *filp,const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *offp)
{
    copy_from_user(msg,buf,count);
    len=count;
    temp=len;

    return count;
}

struct file_operations proc_fops = {
    read: read_proc,
    write: write_proc
};

static void create_new_proc_entry(void)
{
    parent = proc_mkdir(dirname, NULL);
    parent2 = proc_mkdir(dirname2,parent);
    proc_create("private_setting",0644,parent2,&proc_fops);
    msg=kmalloc(GFP_KERNEL,10*sizeof(char));
}


static int proc_init (void)
{
 create_new_proc_entry();
 return 0;
}

static void proc_cleanup(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry("private_setting",parent2);
    remove_proc_entry(dirname2,parent);
    remove_proc_entry(dirname,NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_cleanup);
```

Here a Makefile example to compile code.

```
obj-m := proc_rw_map2.o
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```